# How to make react native top tab and stack navigator display correctly with status bar?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to make an application in react native that has a tab navigation screen as the main screen and a button that goes to another screen. I'm having a problem in making everything looking correct with the status bar.

I have this as my navigator:

```
const tabConfiguration = {
    DecksList: {
        screen: DecksList,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Deck List'
        }
    },
    NewDeck: {
        screen: NewDeck,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'New Deck'
        }
    },
};

const TabNavigator =
    Platform.select({
        ios: createBottomTabNavigator(tabConfiguration),
        android: createMaterialTopTabNavigator(tabConfiguration)
    });

const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
        Main: {
            screen: TabNavigator,
            navigationOptions: {
                header: null
            }
        },
        Deck: {
            screen: Deck,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: 'Deck'
            }
        }
    });

export default createAppContainer(StackNavigator);
```

And my `App.js` is like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <StatusBarView backgroundColor={'red'}
                               barStyle="light-content"/>
                <AppNavigator/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

The `StatusBarView` is:

```
const StatusBarView = props => {
    const {backgroundColor} = props;
    return (
        <View style={{backgroundColor, height: Constants.statusBarHeight}}>
            <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor={backgroundColor} {...props} />
        </View>
    );
};
```

With the code like that, my tab screen like this:
[image]
And my other screen end like this:
[image]
This second screen has a header higher than it should because of the `StatusBarView`. If I remove it, the second screen looks OK:
[image]
But the tabs screen goes behind the status bar:
[image]
Does anyone know how can properly handle this? I need the status bar for one screen (the tabs one) and can't have it for the other screen (the one without tabs).

I made a snack here: https://snack.expo.io/@esscheffer/flashcards-start

Comment: What is use of having a View in StatusBarView.js?

Comment: For the height: `height: Constants.statusBarHeight`. `StatusBar` alone doesn't work; I need the view around it with the height.

Answer (score 0):

This line will solve the issue

> navigationOptions: {   headerForceInset: {top: 'never'},   ... }